# Get custom tables from database in wp-config.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to use another Wordpress installation that gets it's tables from my original Wordpress prefix. I installed both WP installations in the same database with another prefix. I use WP Event Manager and the original prefix is like this:

```
wp_em_events
```

I want the same plugin at my new installation to automatically get it's tables from the orginal one, like the following code already does for the users at my wp-config.php:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users');
```

Is there a rule I can use at my wp-config.php file like the one that gets the users? or is there another way to get the data from the orginal table to the new one?

Comment: Do you mean your wp-config file?

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm sorry! Let me change that right away. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Where does the data currently exist in your original WP site? What is the name of the WP Event Manager table?

Comment: the data (table) is at the MySQL database with the name wp_em_events. I want to get the data from that table for the same plugin at my new site. If possible in the same way as I get my users from the original table. The problem is that I don't know if it's possible to use dynamically for just any table and if it works, what code I need to use.

Comment: It looks like you have the following tables associated with the plugin: EM_EVENTS_TABLE, EM_BOOKINGS_TABLE, EM_LOCATIONS_TABLE, EM_TICKETS_TABLE, EM_TICKETS_BOOKINGS_TABLE, EM_RECURRENCE_TABLE, EM_CATEGORIES_TABLE, EM_META_TABLE. Have you tried doing a `define()` for each of these, in the form of `define('EM_EVENTS_TABLE', 'wp_em_events');`?

Comment: I tried various variable, but it doesn't work. I tried to following line to see if it works with other default wordpress tables:

define('CUSTOM_POST_TABLE', 'wp_posts');

But it doesn't respond...

Comment: Did you try this exact addition: `define('EM_EVENTS_TABLE', 'wp_em_events');`?

Comment: I tried that exact line, didn't work

Comment: Yesterday I was playing with these code lines and again used your code suggestion. I waited for a while and it worked when I refreshed my pages :) Thanks for your help Mevius!

Comment: If you've found a solution, please post it as an answer, and mark it as accepted. Don't add fake tags like "(resolved)" to your title.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiair with how things work here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually it worked using the following code in wp-config.php:

```
define('EM_EVENTS_TABLE', 'wp_em_events');
```

It also works with other (Wordpress) tables:

```
define('POSTS_TABLE', 'wp_posts');
```

Pages are also seen as posts. Be sure to get al tables for a plugin, pages, users etc. . In some cases you also have to get the table with the meta information.